# std::unordered_map iterator returns erased keys, why and how to skip them

Tags: c++11, iterator, key, unordered-map

I am very new to C++ programming and have stumbled across a behaviour that confuses me and makes my coding harder. I have searched for answer a bit and could not find anything - I have also scrolled through C++ reference pages and that did not help either (please don't crucify me if the answer is in there - the page isn't role model for explaining things).  Maybe I am missing something really obvious.

Could someone explain, the following behaviour of std::unordered_map ?

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> test_map;
test_map["test_key_1"] = "test_value_1";
test_map["test_key_2"] = "test_value_2";

std::cout <<  "'test_key_1' value: " << test_map["test_key_1"] << std::endl; // This returns "test_value_1"
std::cout << "test_map size before erase: " << test_map.size() << std::endl; // This returns 2

test_map.erase("test_key_1");

std::cout << "test_map size after erase: " << test_map.size() << std::endl; // This returns 1
std::cout << "'test_key_1' value after erase: " << test_map["test_key_1"] << std::endl; // This returns empty string
std::cout << "'non_existing_key' value: " << test_map["non_existing_key"] << std::endl; // This returns empty string

test_map.rehash(test_map.size()); // I am doing this because vague hints from internet, code behaves
                                  // same way without it.

for (std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it = test_map.begin();
     it != test_map.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << "Key: " << it->first << std::endl;
}
// Above loop return both 'test_key_1' and 'test_key_2'.
// WHY!?
```

Why iterator is returning items that were already erased ? How can I make iterator return only items that are present in map ?
I will be grateful for any help, as I am really lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) to access previously erased elements which

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.

If you need just to search for given key, use [find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) method that returns `map.end()` if element was not found.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have been tacking bug in my code for hours now !